# bar plot with time on x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe (filtered_4_6) from which i extract the occurance of event on an hourly basis with the following code:

```
Filtered_time = filtered_4_6['Date'].dt.time.value_counts()
```

this gives me 24 rows with time in the first column and number of event on the second.
i want to bar plot these 24 bars but can't seem to find how to use the time column as x axis

the result looks like this:

[image]

i've tried different ideas but none works:

```
plt.bar(Filtered_time.index, Filtered_time.values)
```

it is certainly a format conversion error, but i can't figure it out.

i've tried to make Filtered_time a dataframe

```
Filtered_time = pd.DataFrame(filtered_4_6['Date'].dt.time.value_counts())
```

but still get an error

> TypeError: the dtypes of parameters x (object) and width (float64) are incompatible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try plotting with the strings instead:

```
filtered_time = filtered_4_6['Date'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S').value_counts()
filtered_time.plot()
```

Comment: thanks. converting the time column to string works in this case because my times are evenly spaced, but if it wasn't the case, it would have to stay in a numeric format i guess.